# remote service call PeripheralManager.getInstance

Tags: android, remote-server, android-things

run time exception:

> System.err:java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
>   at com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManager.getInstance(PeripheralManager.java:21)
>   at com.afollestad.remotedemo.RemoteService$1.testPeripheralManager(RemoteService.java:33)
>   at com.afollestad.remotedemo.IRemoteAIDL$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteAIDL.java:56)
>   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)

Remote service's Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.afollestad.remotedemo">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />


<application>
    <service
        android:name=".RemoteService"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="service.remote" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private IRemoteAIDL mService;
private TextView result;
private Button connectRemote;
private Button disconnectRemote;
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        Log.d("aidl", "onServiceConnected" + service + "  className  " + className);
        mService = IRemoteAIDL.Stub.asInterface(service);
        try {
            mService.testPeripheralManager();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d("aidl", "onServiceDisconnected");
        mService = null;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        connectRemote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_remote);
        disconnectRemote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect_remote);
        connectRemote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("aidl", "onClick new thread");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("service.remote");
                intent.setPackage("com.afollestad.remotedemo");
                bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            }
        });
        disconnectRemote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("aidl", "onClick");

                unbindService(mConnection);
            }
        });
}}
```

remote service:

```
public class RemoteService extends Service {
private I2cDevice mI2cDevice = null;
private static final String I2C_DEVICE_NAME = "I2C1";
private static final int I2C_ADDRESS = 0x5c;

public Context mContext;
private boolean flag;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

private final IRemoteAIDL.Stub remoteBinder = new IRemoteAIDL.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void testPeripheralManager(){
        Log.d("aidl", "RemoteService PeripheralManager");
        try {
            PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
            Log.d("aidl", "PeripheralManager2");
            mI2cDevice = manager.openI2cDevice(I2C_DEVICE_NAME, I2C_ADDRESS);
            if (mI2cDevice != null) Log.i("aidl", "I2C device open successful!");
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("aidl", "onBind");
    mContext = this;
    return remoteBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    flag = true;
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

I bulid remote service in android things module, call PeripheralManager.getInstance() in remote service.

If any solve this problem, Please help me.

Comment: Please consider adding enough info for others to help when asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a uses-library as part of the Manifest declaration, that would prevent you from installing an apk that requires Android Things in a device that does not have it, which looks like is what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks for answer!Android Developers suggest using android things module,so I change uses-library to module.uses-library was worked.

Comment: glad you got that sorted out.

Comment: @TingYuChen bro can you share how you resolved this? thank you
I tried this : implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'